# Android Studio 2.2 & 2.3 Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio though I have watched a few tutorials before. I am getting the following error when I try to make a project on Android Studio 2.3:
[image]

```
Gradle "Projectname" project refresh failed.
Error:Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle_download2913498326076248476bin' after copy to 'C:\Users\myname\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar'.
```

Its the same error I got before updating from 2.2 to 2.3.
I tried searching the internet but couldn't find a solution.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If "Messages Gradle Sync" recommends an upgrade; you probably already did this.
2. Disable instant run, To do this:
   2.a. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.
   2.b. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
   Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes.
3. Check your anti-virus and turn-off, try again. I have not had this issue, but it was recommended on some older posts with success.

Hope one of these takes care of it. :)

Comment: Turning off the anti-virus fixed it !! Thanks a ton !